# Search for data value with Reg.exe and delete parent key

Tags: batch-file

I am currently trying to use reg query commands to find the data value "teststring" in a value with a random name in HKCU\Software\random characters. I want the script to find the teststring value and then delete the parent key HKCU\Software\random characters. I have tried various ways with scripting and this is what I have so far, however I keep getting syntax errors and can't get reg query to find what I need it to:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Key="HKCU\Software"
set STRING="teststring"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg.exe query "%Key%" /f "%STRING%" /d /s') do (
call :GetValueName Value "%%a"
ECHO reg.exe delete "%Key%" /v "!Value!" /f
)   

goto :eof
:GetValueName
set Return=
for %%a in (%~2) do (
if "%%a"=="REG_SZ" (
    set %1=!Return:~1!&goto :eof
) else (
    set Return=!Return! %%a
)
)
:eof
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Invalid syntax, regardless of how much I change the syntax for REG query.

Comment: I think what @NobodyNada wanted was the exact error message.  Also, general tip for debugging batch files is to remove `@echo off` from the top of the file while debugging.  If the error is in your batch, that line is preventing it from displaying.

Comment: Removed @echo and the script doesn't continue after the loop "for /F" etc.

Comment: Turning echo on should have shown you some of the errors. 1. You quoted variables twice, once in the definition and once in the usage. 2. there is no GOTO :eof at the end of the subroutine, so it would never return. But there are numerous other problems with it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler way to do it.
Remove the ECHO (not the echo) AFTER you are satisfied with what is displayed.

```
@echo off
set "Key=HKCU\Software"
set "STRING=teststring"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('reg query "%Key%" /v test /s /d /f "%STRING%" /t REG_SZ') do (
   echo %%a | findstr /v "REG_SZ" | findstr /v /c:"End of search:" >nul && ECHO reg.exe delete "%%a" /f
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks! There is certainly a lot wrong with what I had, and it's good to learn from good examples, I just couldn't find any. Also, I was wrong about the /v test, the value names are actually random. I removed "test" and now only have /v without a value name and it works flawlessly. I may be doing it wrong, but without /v it breaks. Thanks again!